# WCF Service - Recover from network outage

Tags: c#, wcf, azure

I have a WCF service hosted in a Window service that uses a Azure Service Bus Relay. It uses netTcpRelayBinding in transferMode="Streamed". It exposes on premise functionality to clients that connect to it.

```
<bindings>
  <netTcpRelayBinding>
    <binding name="netTcpRelayBinding" closeTimeout="01:00:00" openTimeout="01:00:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00"
      maxBufferPoolSize="1048576" maxReceivedMessageSize="1048576000" maxBufferSize="1048576" transferMode="Streamed" maxConnections="200"
      listenBacklog="200"/>
  </netTcpRelayBinding>
</bindings>
```

**Question:** How do I make it recover from a network outage and attempt to reopen the connection?

I thought that a faulted or closed event would be fired when I disable the network adapter on my PC during testing but it is never fired.

```
_serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService));

_serviceHost.Faulted += _serviceHost_Faulted;
_serviceHost.Closing += _serviceHost_Closing;
_serviceHost.Closed += _serviceHost_Closed;
_serviceHost.Opened += _serviceHost_Opened;
_serviceHost.UnknownMessageReceived += _serviceHost_UnknownMessageReceived;

_serviceHost.Opened();
```

My last resort is to create a task that polls the service every so often to detect if the service is connected.

Answer (score 0):

My resolution for this scenario is to create background thread inside your windows service that constantly check network interface if status up or down with specified time interval in your loo.

Then, trigger the re-creation of your WCF service but make sure that your properly close and dispose/clean up your service host.

You can use this code to check [network availability](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getisnetworkavailable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
bool networkUp
= System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
```

Or to check a specific [interface's status](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getallnetworkinterfaces%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
NetworkInterface[] networkCards
= System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
```

Other option is, If you don't want threading and loop. You can use [NetworkChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkchange.aspx) and hook an event to re-create your service base on appropriate network status.

```
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged += new 
        NetworkAddressChangedEventHandler(AddressChangedCallback);

NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged += new
        NetworkAvailableEventHandler(networkAvailableEventHandler);

static void AddressChangedCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // do your checking here
     // re-create you service base on appropriate status            
}

static void networkAvailableEventHandler(object sender, NetworkAvailableEventArgs e)
{
    // do your checking here
    // re-create you service base on appropriate status
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response. I'll try it out.